# numCapabilities not showing correct number of cores

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I have been following [concurrency chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) in RWH. I have been trying a sample program mentioned in the book. Following is the code:

test.hs:

```
import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)

main = do
    putStrLn $ "number of cores: " ++ show numCapabilities
```

This is how I execute them:

```
$ ghc -c test.hs
$ ghc -threaded -o test test.o
$ ./test -RTS -N4
number of cores: 1
```

But I seem to have four cores:

```
$ nproc
4
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Produces a big output. But shows four processors. (0..3).
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `./test +RTS -N4 -RTS`?

Comment: @bheklilr Ah yes. Facepalm.

Comment: It happens to all of us, glad it was a simple fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Runtime system options](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-opts-cmdline) are bracket between **`+RTS`** and `-RTS` (although the latter can be omitted). That's also correct in [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html#id674971):

```
$ ./NumCapabilities +RTS -N4 -RTS foo
```

Use `+RTS` instead of `-RTS`:

```
./test +RTS -N4
```

Comment: Note that setting no specific number will make it autodetect the available number of processors, e.g.: `./test +RTS -N`. I personally find it more suitable.